# Calculate sum of several sizes of files in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, grep, awk

I have list of files in a file, `cache_temp`.

In file `cache_temp`:

```
/home/maildir/mydomain.com/een/new/1491397868.M395935P76076.nm1.mydomain.com,S=1740,W=1777
/home/maildir/mydomain.com/een/new/1485873821.M199286P14170.nm1.mydomain.com,S=440734,W=446889
/home/maildir/mydomain.com/td.pr/cur/1491397869.M704928P76257.nm1.mydomain.com,S=1742,W=1779:2,Sb
/home/maildir/mydomain.com/td.pr/cur/1501571359.M552218P73116.nm1.mydomain.com,S=1687,W=1719:2,Sa
/home/maildir/mydomain.com/td.pr/cur/1498562257.M153946P22434.nm1.mydomain.com,S=1684,W=1717:2,Sb
```

I have a simple script for getting the size of files from `cache_temp`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `grep -v ^# ~/cache_temp | grep -v "dovecot.index.cache"`; do
    if [ -f "$i" ]; then
        size=$(du -sh "$i" | awk '{print $1}')
        echo $size
    fi
done
```

I have a list of sizes of files:

```
4,0K
4,0K
4,0K
432K
4,0K
```

How can I calculate the sum of them?

Comment: Don't use the `-h` switch for basic size calculations, taking `k` `M` or `G`'s into account is going to be horribly complex for a simple shell script. Simply adding numbers is trivial http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arithexp.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `stat` instead of `du`:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `grep -v ^# ~/cache_temp | grep -v "dovecot.index.cache"`; do
     [ -f "$i" ] && totalsize=$[totalsize + $(stat -c "%s" "$i")]
done
echo totalsize: $totalsize bytes
```

Comment: Use `$(( ... ))` instead of the undocumented `$[ ... ]` -- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arithmetic-Expansion

Comment: or `(( totalsize += $(stat -c "%s" "$i") ))`

Comment: Please use modern `$(...)` subshells instead of backticks

Answer (score 7):

According to du(1), there is a -c option whose purpose is to produce the grand total.

```
% du -chs * /etc/passwd
92K ABOUT-NLS
196K    NEWS
12K README
48K THANKS
8,0K    TODO
4,0K    /etc/passwd
360K    total
```

Comment: And to just get the human-readable total size: `du -chs * | tail -1 | cut -f1`

Comment: Good option, and so close to a full answer... combined with reading files from `cache_temp` and maybe xargs in case of large lines & add them... I guess you'd have shearn89's answer...

Answer (score 6):

If you need to use the file this snippet is hopefully efficient.

```
xargs -a cache_file stat --format="%s" | paste -sd+ | bc -l
```

The `xargs` is to prevent overflowing the argument limit but getting the max number of files into one invocation of `stat` each time.

Comment: The `stat --format` implies Linux which means you have `xargs -a` to avoid the explicit redirection if you like.

Comment: @tripleee Now thats a valid criticism ;) I changed the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

If you remove the "-h" flag from your "du" command, you'll get the raw byte sizes. You can then add them with the `((a += b))` syntax:

```
a=0
for i in $(find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -s | awk {'print $1'})
do
  ((a += i))
done
echo $a
```

The `-print0` and `-0` flags to find/xargs use null-terminated strings to preserve whitespace.

EDIT: turns out I type slower than @HBruijn comments!

Answer (score 2):

Well... For better or worse, here's my implementation of this. I've always preferred using "while" to read lines from files.

```
#!/bin/bash

SUM=0
while read file; do
    SUM=$(( $SUM + $(stat $file | awk '/Size:/ { print $2 }') ))
done < cache_temp
echo $SUM
```

Per janos' recommendation below:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read file; do
    stat $file
done < cache_temp | awk 'BEGIN { s=0 } $1 == "Size:" { s=s+$2 } END  { print s; }'
```

Comment: With good reason: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: @glennjackman Actually the "reason" link is here https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor but both links are useful

Comment: I see what you're saying.. no sense running stat AND awk "wc -l cache_temp" times.  Use awk one to roll everything up at the end